# print statement inside celery task not working

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to debug `celery` task to see whether it is working properly or not, So I put some `print` statements inside `tasks.py`. While running the project I have observed that task successfully runs but doesn't print anything on the console. How can I debug the celery task.

Comment: Have you restarted celery instance after adding print statement?

Comment: I configured the Celery logging feature and tested  `CELERY_WORKER_REDIRECT_STDOUTS  = False` but still nothing on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Celery actually does the work, tasks are being handled by different Python processes. Depending on how you have things configured, those separate processes might have no access to your console. Instead, they will write to Celery's log file (which can be configured in various ways). Find that file, and you'll see print output from your tasks.

All of that assumes that you have indeed restarted the Celery workers, as suggested by the comment from Gaurav Tomer.

Comment: The log file specified with `-f ~/celery.log` contains celery logs but not the `print` output. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Florent Not sure, but as a debugging step change your `print()` commands to something that writes to your own log file.

Answer (score 2):

For debug celery:

```
from celery import task
from celery.contrib import rdb

@task()
def add(x, y):
    result = x + y
    rdb.set_trace()  # <- set break-point
    return result
```

After running you will see this log:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
    tasks.add[d7261c71-4962-47e5-b342-2448bedd20e8]
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Remote Debugger:6900:
    Please telnet 127.0.0.1 6900.  Type `exit` in session to continue.
[2011-01-18 14:25:44,119: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Remote Debugger:6900:
    Waiting for client...
```

You need to telnet to the port like below:

```
telnet localhost 6900
```

Now you can debug your task. more detail in [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/debugging.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows use the command

```
celery -A <project_name>.celery worker --pool=solo -l INFO
```

restart celery worker with that command